# Is there a way to loop over column names using mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that describes 25 points in the x-y plane for a o of individuals. For 3 individuals that looks like:

```
input_data

   id  x1  y1  x2  y2  x3  y3 ... x25  y25  
   1   9   3   4   7   1   3  ... 2    8     
   2   2   5   3   3   1   7  ... 9    6
   3   5   4   1   8   9   4  ... 2    7
```

I want to compute some complicated number called TMI that is defined for each comparison between x-y pairs. For example for points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), the TMI is:

```
input_data <- input_data %>% 
    mutate(
      A = (x1/x2) + (y1/y2),
      TMI_1_2 = case_when(
      x1 == x2 & y1 == y2 ~ (1-sqrt(pmin((x1*y2)/(x2*y1),(x1*y2)/(x2*y1)))),
      x2/x1 + y2/y1 >= 1 & A == 1 ~ 0,
      TRUE ~ 1)
  )
```

Now, I have to compute this number for all possible pairs of the 25 x-y combinations (those are 300 pairs). The following makes that clear:

```
list_points <- seq.int(25)
table_comparisons <- combn(list_points, 2)
```

What is the optimal way to loop over column names using mutate, such that I can compute the 300 different TMI's that I need?

I though that something like the following would work, but it doesn't:

```
for(i in 1:300) { 
  point1 <- table_comparisons[1,i]
  point2 <- table_comparisons[2,i]

input_data <- input_data %>% 
    mutate(
      A = (xpoint1/xpoint2) + (ypoint1/ypoint2),
      TMI_point1_point2 = case_when(
      xpoint1 == xpoint2 & ypoint1 == ypoint2 ~ (1-sqrt(pmin((xpoint1*ypoint2)/(xpoint2*ypoint1),(xpoint1*ypoint2)/(xpoint2*ypoint1)))),
      xpoint2/xpoint1 + ypoint2/ypoint1 >= 1 & A == 1 ~ 0,
      TRUE ~ 1)
  )
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: Can you complete your question by providing your data in reproducible form? Just type `dput(input_data)` in your console and copy the output into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off transforming your data into x,y pairs before applying the formula. Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

input_data <- tibble(ID = seq(1:5),
                     x1 = runif(5),
                     y1 = runif(5),
                     x2 = runif(5),
                     y2 = runif(5)
                     )

input_data_long <- input_data %>% 
  gather(key, value, -ID) %>% 
  mutate(key1 = stringr::str_extract(key, "[a-zA-Z]"),
         key2 = stringr::str_extract(key, "\\d+")) %>% 
  select(-key) %>% 
  spread(key1, value)
```

Now you can mutate a new column from x & y and then spread the table back into whatever format you want afterwards.